# On Duplicate key proper use? Not working. MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to record IP addresses of users on my site, and I want to have the following flow when the user logs on

```
if (new ip address detected)
  enter in to db
else if (ip address has already been recorded)
  do nothing
```

So that I am not recording every single time a user logs on, just if it is from a new IP address. I thought that I had the correct code, but duplicates are still entering the DB. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
public function insertIpAddress($user_id, $user_ip) {
    return $this->dbHandler->DbQuery("INSERT into user_ip (user_id, ip_address) 
                  VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `user_id` = `user_id`",
                  array($user_id,$user_ip));
}
```

I also tried ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `ip_address` = `ip_address`, but that didn't work.

My DB looks like this:

[image]

and it's coming out like this:

```
ip_address   user_id
10.245.1.38  378
10.245.1.38  378
```

Comment: Maybe set a unique key on the columns?

Comment: In this case you do not even need on duplicate key update, just a unique index / primary key and a simple insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you have a unique index for those two columns. You can add a unique index to your table with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE user_ip 
    ADD UNIQUE `unique_user_ip_address_user_id`(`ip_address`, `user_id`);
```

This creates a unique constraint for the specific combination of IP address and user ID.

---

As a suggestion, you could add a third column to your `user_ip` table to track when the login was attempted and update that field to the current timestamp if there is a duplicate key.

Comment: Great thanks Chris, I'll try this out. I shouldn't need to change the rest of my code then should I?

Comment: The UNIQUE column I created there doesn't show up in 'structure', but it says it was created successfully. Is this normal?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change your code as-is. I'm not terribly familiar with the phpMyAdmin interface; can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_ip` and see what that shows you?

Comment: It seems to have worked without needing to update the code. Thanks Chris!

Comment: No problem, @user1180888